# scons compilation fails when adding shared library

Tags: python, c++, compilation, fortran, scons

I participate in a project containing C++, Fortran and Python, and the compilation is made with scons. I have tried to modify the build scripts to generate a shared library:

```
diff --git a/src/scons/scons_ext/utils.py b/src/scons/scons_ext/utils.py
index bddadd6..896b2aa 100644
--- a/src/scons/scons_ext/utils.py
+++ b/src/scons/scons_ext/utils.py
@@ -650,6 +650,8 @@ to highly recommended debugging and optimization options.
             program_dependencies = [self.rebase_dir(build_dir, target)] \
                                     + src_dependencies + dir_dependencies
             program = env.Program(program_name, program_dependencies)
+            if 'ssh-aerosol.f90' in target:
+                mylib = env.SharedLibrary('ssh-aerosol.so', program_dependencies)
             if program_name in self.command_line_target:
                 BUILD_TARGETS.append(program_name + env["PROGSUFFIX"])
```

However, after the modification, I have to run the compile script ~5 times to generate the `.so` file in the `src` folder. I suspect the scons script is not compiling files in the correct order / does not understand the dependencies between files after my modification.

A development version of the code (to be released with an open-source licence shortly) is available here until 2019/09/30: https://cloud.enpc.fr/s/mKNc4KZF6KKoWiB

EDIT: The number of compile runs needed to obtain a working library is variable. The project is compiled using the `./compile` command in the main directory. The output of the compilation with redirection of stdout and stderr in a log file shows this kind of error:

```
gfortran -o .build/default/include/Module/ModuleAdaptstep.os -c -cpp -O2 -g3 -I /usr/include -cpp -Waliasing -Wampersand -Wsurprising -Wintrinsics-std -Wintrinsic-shadow -Wline-truncation -Wreal-q-constant -fPIC -DPOLYPHEMUS_WITH_AEROSOL_MODULE -DWITHOUT_NACL_IN_THERMODYNAMICS -DPOLYPHEMUS_SINGLE_UNDERSCORE -DPOLYPHEMUS_FASTJX -I. -Iinclude/common -Iinclude/Talos -Iinclude/SeldonData -Iinclude/AtmoData -Iinclude/isorropia_aec -Iinclude/fastJX -Iinclude/CHEMISTRY/cb05en -Iinclude/CHEMISTRY/common_scram -Iinclude/INC -Iinclude/RDB -Iinclude/SOAP -Iinclude/Module -I/usr/include include/Module/ModuleAdaptstep.F90
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_build_env':
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1376:
    _exec_main(parser, values)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1339:
    _main(parser)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1103:
    nodes = _build_targets(fs, options, targets, target_top)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1313:
    jobs.run(postfunc = jobs_postfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Job.py", line 111:
    self.job.start()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Job.py", line 423:
    task.executed()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 237:
    SCons.Taskmaster.OutOfDateTask.executed(self)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Taskmaster.py", line 312:
    t.push_to_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 2910:
    self.get_build_env().get_CacheDir().push(self)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/__init__.py", line 624:
    result = self.get_executor().get_build_env()
f951: Fatal Error: Can't rename module file ‘ldiscretization.mod0’ to ‘ldiscretization.mod’: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminated.
```

```
f951: Fatal Error: Can't rename module file ‘hcongregation.mod0’ to ‘hcongregation.mod’: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [.build/default/include/Module/ModuleCongregation.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

```
   use cThermodynamics
      1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘cthermodynamics.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
include/Module/ModuleDiscretization.F90:7:6:

   use eRedistribution
      1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘eredistribution.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [.build/default/include/Module/ModuleRedistribution.o] Error 1
scons: *** [.build/default/include/Module/ModuleDiscretization.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_build_env':
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1376:
    _exec_main(parser, values)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1339:
    _main(parser)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1103:
    nodes = _build_targets(fs, options, targets, target_top)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1313:
    jobs.run(postfunc = jobs_postfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Job.py", line 111:
    self.job.start()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Job.py", line 423:
    task.executed()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 237:
    SCons.Taskmaster.OutOfDateTask.executed(self)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Taskmaster.py", line 312:
    t.push_to_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/FS.py", line 2910:
    self.get_build_env().get_CacheDir().push(self)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Node/__init__.py", line 624:
    result = self.get_executor().get_build_env()
```

Comment: What exactly happens, what is the complete output of the build command. I am afraid we need a [mcve]. An external repository does not count for several reasons. It is not minimal, but foremost the link can get broken any time making the question useless for future visitors.

Comment: Agree with @VladimirF - What do you do with mylib?  Assuming you want to link it with the Program one line prior, you need to add that to the libs..

Comment: @VladimirF I will be able to post a link to the repository when publicly released. (I will also be able to provide a link to the exact git commit corresponding to the issue referenced here).

Comment: @user1824346 That does not change much. The code for a question is supposed to be contained in the question itself, not in an outside repository. It doesn;t matter if the links goes to your website or to github.

Comment: There are some French (or a similar language I do not understand) messages in your output. Try to add `LANG="C"` in front of the command you run.

Comment: @VladimirF I fixed the language issue. However, I can not provide a small example which could fit in a post. Even the output + error of the compile command overflows the number of characters allowed...

Comment: But in the output you show we are still missing the compile command that generated the error.

Comment: @VladimirF I am updating the question accordingly, but the command is simply './compile' from inside the repository.

Comment: @bdbaddog I am not doing anything with the new variable `mylib`. This statement leads to the generation of the `.so` shared library. I have to confess I do not really understand the underlying mechanism.

Comment: Not your command, the gfortran command that scons is issuing for.you.

Comment: @VladimirF I have updated the first error message with a gfortran command. It was obtained with a serial compilation (-j1 in the compile script).

Comment: @VladimirF I think I have solved the issue. I will update the question when our project is released open-source. However, I understand pointing to an external resource is a problem, but I was not able to elaborate a smaller self-consistent example for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the compilation issue seems to be:

```
             program_dependencies = [self.rebase_dir(build_dir, target)] \
                                     + src_dependencies + dir_dependencies
             program = env.Program(program_name, program_dependencies)
             # Generate shared library for ssh-aerosol
             if 'ssh-aerosol.f90' in target:
-                mylib = env.SharedLibrary('ssh-aerosol.so', program_dependencies)
+                mylib = env.SharedLibrary('ssh-aerosol.so', 'ssh-aerosol.f90')
             if program_name in self.command_line_target:
                 BUILD_TARGETS.append(program_name + env["PROGSUFFIX"])

             # In case another SConstruct wants to depend on this source
             # directory:
```